# Get JSON collection inside another JSON in VB.NET

Tags: json, vb.net, json.net

I have a JSON object de-serialized using Newtonsoft JSON in VB.NET How can I get a specific key  type value when it has a JSON inside another JSON. Please see JSON response below

I want to get the identity status based on identity type

[image]

My code attempt:

```
Dim jsonResult As String = myReader.ReadToEnd() 'My json line above
 Dim jsonObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonResult)
 Dim ContactNum = jsonObject("owner")("identity_statuses")("identity_status")

For i As Integer = 0 To ContactNum.Count
      Dim arr = ContactNum(i)
Next
```